# How do I get customer's coupon list?

Tags: magento2.4, coupon, coupon-codes

What should I do if I want to display the user's coupon in the checkout cart?  thanks a lot for you help

i used ambab-module-couponlist extension,Error shippingAddress is NULL While applying coupons

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the below module for this and customize this module if you have any custom requirements regarding this:

https://marketplace.magento.com/ambab-module-couponlist.html

Comment: I used this extension but couldn't get a coupon list

Comment: This extension showing the available coupons on the cart page. On your cart page, "view coupon list" link is showing?

Comment: yes,it will show.But the coupon list is blank

Comment: Inside coupon admin configuration, there is a new field created named "Visible in listing". Check this field. Or detailed info, you can check the extension demo images and read the instructions for this extension.

Comment: I can already see the coupon list.but I can't get Use Auto Generation coupons

Comment: What should I do if I want to obtain automatically generated coupons that customers receive?